# How to target the first instance of a nested class?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to target the first instance of the class ".container" only from a nested repeating block.  Here is the structure for clarity:

```
<div id="home-event-block>
  <div class="event_container">
     <div>Some Text </div>
     <div class="container">More Text </div> <!-- Target this only -->
  </div>
  <div class="event_container">
     <div>Some Text </div>
     <div class="container">More Text </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event_container">
     <div>Some Text </div>
     <div class="container">More Text </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can obviously target every instance of "container" but I am at a loss for getting only the first instance of "container" on the page. Thoughts?

Comment: Does the `.container` class only appear inside the `.event_container`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:first-of-type/first-child` to target `.event_container`  then select `container`

```css
.event_container:first-of-type .container {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div id="home-event-block">
  <div class="event_container">
    <div>Some Text </div>
    <div class="container">More Text </div>
    <!-- Target this only -->
  </div>
  <div class="event_container">
    <div>Some Text </div>
    <div class="container">More Text </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event_container">
    <div>Some Text </div>
    <div class="container">More Text </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to be more specific in your CSS rule you can target your parent `home-event-block`  and use the the child selector  `>`

```css
#home-event-block>.event_container:first-of-type>.container {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-event-block">
  <div class="event_container">
    <div>Some Text </div>
    <div class="container">More Text </div>
    <!-- Target this only -->
  </div>
  <div class="event_container">
    <div>Some Text </div>
    <div class="container">More Text </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event_container">
    <div>Some Text </div>
    <div class="container">More Text </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Notes:**

- you were missing a `"` after `home-event-block`
- you can use `:first-of-type` because every sibling is the same element `div` otherwise you couldn't

Comment: Thank you dippas, that was making me banana's. :D I will accept your answer as soon as  the time limit drops off.

Answer (score 0):

One way is `#home-event-block > div.event_container:first-of-type > div.container`

```css
#home-event-block>div.event_container:first-of-type>div.container {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-event-block">
  <div class="event_container">
    <div>Some Text </div>
    <div class="container">More Text </div>
    <!-- Target this only -->
  </div>
  <div class="event_container">
    <div>Some Text </div>
    <div class="container">More Text </div>
  </div>
  <div class="event_container">
    <div>Some Text </div>
    <div class="container">More Text </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This breaks down to:

- `#home-event-block` (Select the element with the ID `home-event-block`)
- `> div.event_container:first-of-type` (Select the first div child only if it has the class `event_container`)
- `> div.container` (Select the div with the class `container`)